# Calculate rolling weekly/monthly change, using daily price data (with datetime stamps) in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have a pandas dataframe of daily stock price data, which is datetime stamped. Wondering the easiest way to create new columns which have weekly, monthly, or annual growth rates for this price data, but on a rolling basis.

Note that my daily price data only includes records for where there has been a change in price. i.e. no records for non-trading days.

For example, I want to generate something like this:

```
|            | daily | weekly | monthly |
|------------|-------|--------|---------|
| 1/01/2000  | 2.00  | NaN    | NaN     |
| 3/01/2000  | 4.05  | NaN    | NaN     |
| 4/01/2000  | 2.10  | NaN    | NaN     |
| 5/01/2000  | 2.15  | NaN    | NaN     |
| 6/01/2000  | 3.20  | NaN    | NaN     |
| 7/01/2000  | 3.25  | 0.625  | NaN     |
| 10/01/2000 | 3.30  | -0.185 | NaN     |
| 11/01/2000 | 3.35  | 0.595  | NaN     |
| 12/01/2000 | 3.40  | 0.581  | NaN     |
| 13/01/2000 | 4.45  | 0.391  | NaN     |
| 14/01/2000 | 2.50  | -0.231 | NaN     |
| 17/01/2000 | 3.55  | 0.076  | NaN     |
| 18/01/2000 | 4.60  | 0.373  | NaN     |
| 19/01/2000 | 2.65  | -0.221 | NaN     |
| 20/01/2000 | 4.70  | 0.056  | NaN     |
| 21/01/2000 | 3.75  | 0.500  | NaN     |
| 24/01/2000 | 2.80  | -0.211 | NaN     |
| 25/01/2000 | 3.85  | -0.163 | NaN     |
| 26/01/2000 | 3.90  | 0.472  | NaN     |    
| 27/01/2000 | 2.95  | -0.372 | NaN     |
| 28/01/2000 | 3.00  | -0.200 | NaN     |
| 31/01/2000 | 4.05  | 0.446  | NaN     |
| 1/02/2000  | 3.10  | -0.195 | 0.550   |
| 2/02/2000  | 3.15  | -0.192 | 0.575   |
| 3/02/2000  | 5.20  | 0.763  | 0.284   |
| 4/02/2000  | 4.25  | 0.417  | 1.024   |
| 7/02/2000  | 5.30  | 0.309  | 0.631   |
| 8/02/2000  | 4.35  | 0.403  | 0.338   |
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The weekly calculation is easy enough, seems like you can just lag it by five days:

```
shifted = data['daily'].shift(5)
data['weekly'] = (data['daily'] - shifted) / shifted
```

Monthly is harder because it seems like where there's a date missing you want to take the previous available date (i.e. on 2/2/2000 you compare to 1/1/2000 because there is no 2/1/2000). Or at least I think that's what you want from looking at the result. To do that you need to fill in the missing dates first using `data_range()` and `reindex()` using the "pad" fill method to take the previous day's value.

```
data.index = pd.to_datetime(data.index, dayfirst=True)
lag_data = data.reindex(pd.date_range(data.index.min(), data.index.max()), method='pad')
lag_data.index = lag_data.index + pd.DateOffset(31)
monthly = (data['daily'] - lag_data['daily']) / lag_data['daily']
data.join(monthly.rename('monthly'))
```

Comment: That's perfect, thanks very much. Easily adaptable to annual rates too.